# unable to import dependencies in eclipse java project

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket

I have the following import code in eclipse java class:

```
package test.mycode;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

}
```

I have the following external dependencies added to the project:

javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar

javax-websocket-client-api-1,1,jar

Eclipse gives error for all javax import statements with the message "The package javax.websocket is not accessible".  How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does in the default package deleting the `module-info.java` file fix your issue?

Comment: I deleted module-info.java file.  The issue is not fixed.

Comment: Make also sure, both JAR files (when they contain the same package) are on the classpath, not on the modulepath. Be aware that a different error might shown at the same location.